# Is it possible to add labeled points to a dc.js line chart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I like dcjs, http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6584483 but the problem is I see no labels anywhere for the line chart (Events Per Hour). Is it possible to add a label that shows up just above the data point, or even better, within a circular dot at the tip of each data point?

Comment: There is a PR for this, please try it out and leave a review there. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1045 The circular dot idea is cool, I guess that would work if the font and text were really small.

Comment: The dot could also be bigger, assuming there are fewer data points and relative to size of the chart. How do you use such pull requests, do you just copy and paste the snippet into your version of the library? Usually I just use bower and get latest release.

Comment: Yeah, you can copy and paste if you are unfamiliar with git/npm/grunt, that may be easier. We do have an option to always show the dots; I guess sizing the dots to fit the text would be the hard part, but I've done that elsewhere. It's a cool idea.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to apply the concepts in the pull request and came up with:

```
function getLayers(chart){
  var chartBody = chart.chartBodyG();
  var layersList = chartBody.selectAll('g.label-list');

  if (layersList.empty()) {
    layersList = chartBody.append('g').attr('class', 'label-list');
  }

  var layers = layersList.data(chart.data());
  return layers;
}

function addDataLabelToLineChart(chart){
  var LABEL_FONTSIZE = 50;
  var LABEL_PADDING = -19;
  var layers = getLayers(chart);
  layers.each(function (d, layerIndex) {
    var layer = d3.select(this);
    var labels = layer.selectAll('text.lineLabel')
    .data(d.values, dc.pluck('x'));

    labels.enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'lineLabel')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('x', function (d) {
        return dc.utils.safeNumber(chart.x()(d.x));
      })
      .attr('y', function (d) {
        var y = chart.y()(d.y + d.y0) - LABEL_PADDING;
        return dc.utils.safeNumber(y);
      })
      .attr('fill', 'white')
      .style('font-size', LABEL_FONTSIZE + "px")
      .text(function (d) {
        return chart.label()(d);
      });

      dc.transition(labels.exit(), chart.transitionDuration())
        .attr('height', 0)
        .remove();
  });
}
```

I changed the "layers" to be a new group rather than using the existing "stack-list" group so that it would be added after the data points and therefore render on top of them.

Here is a fiddle of this hack: https://jsfiddle.net/bsx0vmok/

[image]